# Gremlin collect all first level Vertices if the second level vertex has a specific property

Tags: gremlin

My graph looks something like

[image]

From `A`, I need to collect all the `B` i.e. B1, B2,..BN which are connected to `C` and C has a specific property value.

Answer (score 2):

Without having actual data this may not be quite right but I think you are looking for something like this:

```
g.V().hasLabel('A').
  out().hasLabel('B').
  where(out().hasLabel('C').has('someprop','somevalue'))
```